# next_token searchtweets API Twitter

Tags: python, api, python-twitter, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to use **searchtweets** (full archive sandbox API Twitter ) to retrive old tweets but I've problem with the next_token.

After doing a first request and getting the next_token (rs.rs.next_token), I'm trying to use it in a second query **but I obtain the same results.** I was expecting to get the the results by that token.

```html
rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
                   max_results=100, 
                  **premium_search_args,
                  next = 'eyJtYXhJZCI6MTMzMTM3MzA4NzI2NzQyNjMwOH0=')
```